# Android - manually select layout type

Tags: android, layout

I developed an Android app and tested it on two devices:

Galaxy S2 320x533dp
Galaxy S4 360x640dp

Both are "normal long" displays, but since the S2 is short than the S4, I cannot use the full S4 screen.
I would prefer to give the S2 the "normal not long" layout.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it would be good to use a scaling layout, e.g. RelativeLayout. If you use a layout type which does not fulfill your expectations you can also choose the layout in your onCreate() method.

```
//in onCreate()
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
if (/*condition whether dimensions match certain phone*/) {
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
}
```

But I totally would try to avoid things like this. You will have to cover many different dimensions manually which is a lot of work and obviously bad practice. Try to use something scaling!

Comment: Your way doesn't work because my layouts have the same name but are in different folders. "layout" and "layout-long".
I use RelativeLayout, but it is still too long because the spacing between the elements is in dp.